Equivalent assumptions in Revealed Preference and Classical Preference Theories
I have read that there are dualities between Revealed Preference Theory and Classical Preference Theory.
Suppose, I have $X$ as the set of all conceivable choices, and $\mathscr{B} \subseteq 2^X$ the set of all budget sets. Suppose, $\succeq$ is a relation on $X$.
If $C: \mathscr{B} \rightarrow 2^X$ is the choice function generated from $\succeq$, that is, for any $B \in \mathscr{B}$,
$$C(B) = \{x\in X | x \succeq y, \forall y \in B\}$$
then what conditions imposed on $C$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are together equivalent to the rationality of $\succeq$?
For example, clearly, if $\mathscr{B} = \phi$, then no condition on $C$ would guarantee rationality, as they would be vacuously true for all relations on $X$. Similarly, I know that WARP is weaker than rationality, if no conditions are put on $\mathscr{B}$, but if all sets of three or less distinct elements of $X$ are included in $\mathscr{B}$, then WARP guarantees rationality.
So, reiterating my question, what is the set of assumptions to be put on $\mathscr{B}$ and $C$ such that taken together, they are necessary and sufficient for the rationality of $\succeq$?
